# Expressing a real number by a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to prove the existence of $z_n \in (0,1,2,...,9 )$ with $ n \in \mathbb N_0$ so that $$x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{z_n 10^{-n}}$$ with 
$x \in \mathbb R^+$ . 
The problem I have to deal with is that $x$ is by definition an element of the positive real numbers, but the specification only allows $0 \le x \lt 10$ . 
For example, I can't express $x=11$ by the sum.
Am I right with that?
(Sorry for any english mistakes, I am non-native ...)

Comment: Yes, you’re right: the largest number that you can express, with $z_n=9$ for all $n$, is $9.999\ldots=10$. If you were to require $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, you could get precisely the real numbers in $[0,1]$.

Comment: So....how would you deal with that? $z_n$ is the value of the n-th decimal place - okay, easy, but somehow I dont understand what my exercise is then.

Comment: (I’ll use the version with $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.) My guess is that you’re to start with an arbitrary $x\in[0,1]$ and prove the existence of a sequence $\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ such that the series is convergent and converges to $x$. My first thought would be to choose $z_1$ maximal such that $\frac{z_1}{10}\le x$ and let $x_1=x-\frac{z_1}{10}$, then continue recursively to define the $z_n$’s. Then you have to show that the partial sums converge to $x$.

Comment: Well, the previous task on this exercise was to prove convergence of the series...If I take that and show that it's monotonically increasing, wouldn't this be acceptable too?

Comment: By construction it’s pretty clearly monotonically increasing and bounded above by $x$, so you know that it converges; all that remains is to show that the limit is actually $x$ and not something smaller.

Answer (score 0):

10.999... Is equal to 11. And you can represent 10.999... with given sum.

There are many ways to prove this. One proof is more formal than another. But let's consider an easy one. Let's say.
S = 10.999...
10*S = 109.999...
9*S = 109.999... - 10.999...
9*S = 99. 
S = 11.

Comment: You’ve misunderstood both the problem and the OP’s question; this simply isn’t relevant, I’m afraid.

Comment: How can I get 11 with the sum? 
The largest value I can express is
$9 + 0.9 + 0.09 + 0.009 ... $
And this will always be less than 10

Comment: 9 + 0.9 + 0.09 + ... is actually equal to 10. I'm not going to re-invent the wheel here so you can easily find (even on wikipedia) several proofs to this equation.

Comment: Excuse me I've read your comment wrong. You can represent 11 by 1*10 + 9*10^-1 + 9*10^-2....

Comment: @Auberon: No, you cannot, because the power $10^1$ is not available.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see. Then I think OP is right with his statement that $0 <= x < 10$ except x can also be 10.